# PHP why using newline in source code

Tags: php

I read on php.net site and see a lot of code there try to echo "\n".
What is the point of doing so, because we need to view source to see new break. Why don't just simply use `<br />` tag?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: well, sometimes you want to read the generated output. reading the whole output as a single line is a bit though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly the program is intended to be run from a command-line, rather than a browser?

Possibly it is run in a browser, but output as `text/plain`?

Possibly it is in HTML, but printed inside a `<pre>` tag?

Possibly it's just because the author wanted to have it looking neat when he does "View Source" from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Php output does not need to be HTML, it can be anything. If PHP is run from console, `<br />` would be displayed as `<br />`, while `"\n"` are newlines.

Answer (score 0):

When you run script from console with using

```
<br />
```

you don't see breakline just these symbols